# WPF WinForms multi-level hybrid nesting

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

I read on MSDN and other websites (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751797.aspx and http://www.abhishekshukla.com/wpf/advanced-wpf-part-5-of-5-interop-in-windows-presentation-foundation/) that multilevel hybrid nesting of WPF and WinForms controls is not supported...

I have an application where a WPF window has a WindowsFormsHost where inside that a WPF control is hosted in an ElementHost. This WPF control contains other WinForms controls which are also in WinFormsHost. 
In short: WPF -> WinForms -> WPF -> WinForms.

So far I did not have any problems with that. After finding that small note on the MSDN page I'm wondering what exactly is not supported on that scenario, since it works for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: I did a ctrl+F of the word "hybrid" in the link you posted and didn't find that in the whole text. As an aside. Why are you doing that? Wouldn't it be preferrable to stay with WPF and drop useless winforms altogether?

Comment: I found the word hybrid in both links, in the MSDN link its in the box called Note which starts after 3 lines of introduction text. I'm doing this because I have to use legacy WinForms controls and want to develop all new stuff with WPF. Sometimes I need to put a new WPF control in a WinForms control, otherwise I have to develop new controls in WinForms which I definitly not want to

Comment: May I ask what are the winforms controls that you need?... Also, beside your need to use it, I really don't think its a good idea to intermix them both in such ways

Comment: I agree that's not a good idea but if you need to migrate step by step you have no other choice... The controls consist mostly of a combination of the following WinForms controls: Label, TextBox and PictureBox

Comment: but I mean, is there anything special about those that you cannot directly do in WPF?

Comment: I cannot afford to convert everything at once

Answer (score 2):

I would say the sense of "not supported" is "at your own risk". Most things will work, some things will not work, and it depends on your particular application whether the results will be acceptable. Or maybe you'll achieve results that are acceptable after some hacky workarounds are  in place. MS aren't going to go out of there way to make it work.

I've worked with a project which contained a WinForms-WPF-WinForms nesting, and in general that worked - well enough to not rewrite the WinForms component. *Focus* is an issue - the nested control does not behave quite as you'd expect relating to focus gained/lost events, and keyboard focus can get stuck in the nested control. There may be a difference between whether the host element thinks it has focus and whether the contained control does. So I'd suggest focusing your testing around user input events and focus.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! May I ask how deeply the nesting was in your project?

Comment: In that case only WF-WPF-WF as described (ie reusing legacy control within new WPF component in existing app).

Comment: I think it also depends on what type your window is, if it is WinForms you are using the WinForms infrastructure and WPF wraps into it, if it is WPF you are using the WPF infrastructure and WinForms is wrapped into it. And I think the WPF infrastructure should better interact with WinForms than the other way?